# Filtrando consulta query builder en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

tengo una consulta que hace lo siguiente.

DB::table('usuarios')
    ->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('users', 'usuarios.user_id', '=', 'users.id')

```
->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id',
```

->select('usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id', 
     DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))
 DB::raw('count(nombre) as nombre'))

```
->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id'])
```

->groupBy(['usuario_ad', 'name', 'last_name', 'tipos_usuarios_id']) 
    ->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')
->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')

```
->paginate(20);
```

->paginate(20);

estos son los campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta consulta lo que hace es que si por ejemplo en la tabla usuarios en el campo usuario_ad como admin con user_id 2, me tome todos los usuarios que se relacionen con este admin y me los sume, osea que si admin tiene 5 usuarios, vaparecería en la tabla admin 5, esta parte funciona bien, se veria asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca el resultado suma la cantidad de usuarios (Numero usuarios) agregados, por cada (usuario) que lo agrego.

Ahora debo hacer una modificacion un tanto mas compleja, tengo estos datos en la tabla users.

Ahora debo hacer una modificación un tanto mas complicada. tengo esta tabla, en donde refer indica el usuario que agrego otros usuarios, adminad tiene un rol referido, que agrego a otros referidos como pgestion, andgarcia, adminpal, s3r3ft, y todos estos pueden agregar usuarios sin rol en la tabla usuarios.

tabla users

| refer    | username        | name             |
    +----------+-----------------+------------------+
+----------+-----------------+------------------+
    | alfa     | adminad         | Admin            |
| alfa     | adminad         | Admin            |
    | adminad  | pgestion        | pgestion         |
| adminad  | pgestion        | pgestion         |
    | adminad  | andgarcia       | andres           |
| adminad  | andgarcia       | andres           |
    | adminad  | adminpal        | administrador    |
| adminad  | adminpal        | administrador    |
    | adminad  | s3r3ft          | s3r3ft           |
| adminad  | s3r3ft          | s3r3ft           |
    | adminad  | wslopez         | wilson           |
| adminad  | wslopez         | wilson           |
    | adminpal | batichica       | G                |
| adminpal | batichica       | G

tabla usuarios

+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
    | usuario_ad | nombre            | apellido          |
| usuario_ad | nombre            | apellido          |
    +------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+------------+-------------------+-------------------+
    | adminad    | prueba1           | prueba2           |
| adminad    | prueba1           | prueba2           |
    | adminad    | pruebados         | pruebados         |
| adminad    | pruebados         | pruebados         |
    | andgarcia  | andres            | garcia pulgarin   |
| andgarcia  | andres            | garcia pulgarin   |
    | andgarcia  | alejandra         | garcia pulgarin   |
| andgarcia  | alejandra         | garcia pulgarin   |
    | andgarcia  | maria elena       | pulgarin          |
| andgarcia  | maria elena       | pulgarin          |

Entonces lo que he tratado de hacer, es hacer un reporte como el primero que funciona, que me muestra la cantidad de usuarios de adminad, andgarcia, Bombom, si no que aparezcan con base a la columna refer y username de la tabla usuarios en el reporte, por ejemplo

referido que crea   referido agregado  Cantidad de usuarios votantes
    adminad             prueba1                       5
adminad             prueba1                       5
    adminad             pruebados                     6
adminad             pruebados                     6
    adminad             andgarcia                     2
adminad             andgarcia                     2
    adminad             bombom                        1
adminad             bombom                        1

Noten que el primer reporte que explique, muestra la cantidad general por un usuario referido que tiene usuarios votantes, mientras que acá quiero que se muestre el referido que los creo, el referido creado y la cantidad usuarios que ha adicionado este, un tanto complejo, espero me entiendan.